Im trying to animate a character in Windows form but forget the animation the character isn't even moving when I press any of the keys
namespace FinalProject2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool goLeft, goRight, goUp, goDown;
        int playerX;
        int playerY;
        int steps = 0;
        int playerSpeed = 8;
        int playerHeight = 100;
        int playerWidth = 100;
        int slowDownFrameRate = 0;
        Image player;
        List<string> playerMovements = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetUp();
        }



        private void TimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (goLeft && playerX > 0) 
            {
                playerX -= playerSpeed;
            }

            if (goRight && playerX + playerWidth < this.ClientSize.Width) 
            {
                playerX += playerSpeed;
            }

            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private void FormPaintEvent(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics Canvas = e.Graphics;
            Canvas.DrawImage(player, playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        }

        private void KeyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                goLeft = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                goRight = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                goUp = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                goDown = true;
            }
        }

        private void SetUp() 
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("ProjectBackground.png");
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            //movements of player
            playerMovements = Directory.GetFiles("ProjectPlayerMovements", "*.png").ToList();
            player = Image.FromFile(playerMovements[7]);
        }

        private void KeyIsUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                goLeft = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                goRight = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                goUp = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                goDown = false;
            }
        }

    }
}

It just shows the character and the background, but doesn't do anything when I press the keys.

Learn using the debugger to find out if the keys get picked up etc..

We just see a bunch of eventhandlers but don't see how they are connected to what actual event.
